# Compile Error - Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek, make

I'm having a Ubuntu(20.04) installed ASUS laptop which having external headset's mic not recognizing problem (i.e. even if I plugged a mic supported headset it uses laptop's in-build microphone).

So I thought installing Realtek High Audio driver will fix the issue and tried to install the driver provided by [Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software).

Followed the instructions stated in the downloaded package itself.

But when I trying to compile the code using `make` command, the following error coming out and stops the compiling.

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-28-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/vajira/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa  CPP="gcc -E" CC="gcc" modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-28-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:167: compile] Error 2
```

I have gone through several forums regarding this issue, but couldn't get sorted out yet.

Can someone help me to fix this quickly??

Answer (score 2):

On the realtek site it states:

> Linux driver (3.0)
> It only supports kernel version under 3.18.
> Since you're apparently using kernel version 5.4.0 it won't compile.

Unfortunately, I'm facing a very similar issue and haven't managed to resolve it so far.