# Ubuntu 20.04, Skype unable to properly record sound

Tags: sound, 20.04, skype, microphone

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed Skype on it. When I am calling a client, I am able to hear client's voice but client is unable to hear my voice. The test call feature of Skype returns a noise and not my voice.

UPDATE:

I am able to record voice in audio-recorder but there is a heavy background noise.

Comment: Try to install audio-recorder. Then record your voice. Does your recorded voice sounds well?

Comment: @BernardDecock At first it does not, as it is pointed to "built-in analog stereo audio output". But then I change it to "built-in analog stereo microphone" and then it records perfectly.

Comment: @BernardDecock But I am getting a heavy background noise in audio-recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from non-availibility of Realtek Generic driver for Ubuntu 20.04. It has a kernel of 5.4. But Realtek driver for Linux supports Kernel only upto 3.0. Thus the laptops having Realtek sound card will keep facing this problem unless Realtek releases updated drivers.

Source - [Compile Error - Realtek High Definition Audio Codecs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234664/compile-error-realtek-high-definition-audio-codecs)